# Is it possible to insert a Gmail signature either at my cursor, or at least above replies?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail signature set up, but its default behavior seems to be to insert signatures at the very bottom of the mail.

In situations where I'm writing a reply in a long chain of exchanges, the signature is effectively lost at the very bottom, below all the previously referenced replies.

What I want is for my signature to appear below the new text I am writing, which is at the very top, but above all the replies that are included at the bottom of the mail.

The easiest thing would be for me to somehow be able to insert a signature at the cursor, so when I finish writing, I can just place it. I thought pressing the signature icon would do this, but apparently not. In any case, I am open to any suggestion that lets me easily place the signature in the desired position.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you ask for by using a [template](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308990).

1. Create and save a new template with **just** your signature.
2. Whenever you want to reply, hit the reply button and then choose your signature from `INSERT TEMPLATE`.

[image]

This way you can write over, under or anywhere you like in relation to your signature.

Comment: **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.